# Kibana Windows zip distribution takes too long to unzip

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have downloaded latest kibana OSS zip file from [here](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/kibana-oss-6-3-0).
However I noticed its taking too long to extract the zip on Windows default zip extract utility.

[image]

Is it meant to be this much time consuming Or do I need to change anything on my machine to improve it ?

Comment: on a ssd for kib-7.13 it took 20 minutes for me

Answer (score 14):

The default unzipping functionality in Windows cannot, for whatever reason, unzip Kibana. It times out when I try it and I've seen others have the same problem. I've never had this issue with anything *besides* Kibana, so I'm pretty confident the problem is with Kibana.

The way I unzipped it in the end was by downloading 7zip. Then I right clicked on the Kibana .zip folder and unzipped it with 7zip. Took like 5 minutes which is ridiculous but it still worked.

[Get 7zip here](https://www.7-zip.org/)

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a known issue on Windows, but I'm not sure what can be done against it (other than convince Microsoft to add a better implementation).

An alternative ZIP client should help with the problem though if I remember correctly.

Comment: Please cite your source.

Comment: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/best-archiver-even-better-than-7zip-and-uharc/2/. Since it depends on the archive, I can say that I've seen bad performance with the default Windows ZIP program and Kibana.

Comment: Specifically, I was looking for a source of a known issue on Windows. Does Microsoft know of the issue?

Comment: I don't know (I'm not even using Windows). All I can say is that this is a known issue for Kibana users.